# ViM: how to put string from input dialog in a list

Tags: list, string, vim

VIM: Does anyone know how to put a string from an input dialog in a list?

p.e.:

the string "3,5,12,15"

to:

```
list item[1] = 3
list item[2] = 5
list item[3] = 12
etc.
```

and how can I know how many list items there are?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From `:h E714`

```
:let l = len(list)              " number of items in list
:let list = split("a b c")      " create list from items in a string
```

---

In your case,

```
let string = "3,5,7,19"
let list = split(string, ",")
echo len(list)
```

Comment: @N 1.1, thank yo very much. I checked also :h E714, didn't know this page

Answer (score 2):

Use `split`, `len` and `empty` functions:

```
let list=split(string, ',')
let list_length=len(list)
" If all you want is to check whether list is empty:
if empty(list)
    throw "You must provide at least one value"
endif
```

Note that if you want to get a list of numbers out of the string, you will have to use map to transform list elements into numbers:

```
let list=map(split(string, ','), '+v:val')
```

Most of time you can expect strings be transformed into numbers, but sometimes such transformation is not done.